# Group enabled checkboxes above disabled ones in a list

Tags: jquery, sorting, checkbox

I'm trying to re-order a list of checkboxes so that enabled checkboxes (with their labels) are grouped above disabled checkboxes (with their labels).  I'm afraid I just don't understand the vaguely related posts I've seen so far on this and don't really know where to start.  All I've been able to achieve is the ability to select enabled boxes using:     `$('.CountryListBoxClass_prodn').find("input:checkbox:enabled").parent()...`

Furthermore, I'd like a horizontal line to be put between the 2 groups, although sometimes there won't be any disabled checkboxes so a line won't always be needed. 
 Not sure if this is possible.  Many thanks for any help anyone can offer. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/37kjbhx6/

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js


<input type='button' id='ReformatCountries' value='Reformat checkboxes' />

<div class="CountryListBoxClass_prodn">
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN40" value="Austria" />Austria</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN100" value="Bulgaria" />Bulgaria</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN191" value="Croatia" />Croatia</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN208" value="Denmark" />Denmark</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN233" value="Estonia" />Estonia</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN276" value="Germany" />Germany</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN348" value="Hungary" />Hungary</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN372" value="Ireland" />Ireland</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN428" value="Latvia" />Latvia</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN470" value="Malta" />Malta</label>
</div>
```

.

```
$(function() {

// Disable selected checkboxes
  $('.CountryListBoxClass_prodn label input[id="UN100"], input[id="UN191"], 
input[id="UN372"], input[id="UN470"]').prop('disabled', true);

// ---------

  $('#ReformatCountries').click(function() {

    // Group 'enabled' checkboxes above 'disabled'

  });

}); // End function
```

.

```
.CountryListBoxClass_prodn label {
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid transparent;
width: 213px;
background-color: white;
margin: 0px 7px 2px 0px;
}

.CountryListBoxClass_prodn input {
position: relative;
vertical-align: middle;
bottom: 1px;
margin-right: 10px;
}

.CountryListBoxClass_prodn {
border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
Padding: 10px 0px 0px 5px;
background-color: #fcfcfc;
overflow-y: scroll;
font-family: "Verdana";
font-size: 11px;
}
```

Comment: Please, have a look at my "late" answer. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by selecting only the enabled checkboxes, and then prepending them to `CountryListBoxClass_prodn`. To add the horizontal line, just filter the last enabled checkbox, and insert after:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]')
  .filter(':enabled')
  .parent()
  .prependTo('.CountryListBoxClass_prodn')
  .filter(':last').
  .after('<hr />');
```

You might want to add a class to your checkboxes and use that as your selector (the code above will select all checkboxes on the page).

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37kjbhx6/2/)

Comment: Wow, you made that look so easy and I've learned well.  Your help much appreciated.

Comment: the divider `<hr />` will be inserted everytime you click the button

Comment: Just wrap the above code in a condition so that it'll only run if there are any disabled checkboxes present

Answer (score 2):

See below how to `clone` and element node before removing and reinserting it below the divider, this uses `documentFragment` that is preferred in such kind of methods where you are inserting the elements into the `DOM` you should not insert them directly one by one into the `document` but instead you should use `documentFragment` which results in way faster and improves the script time. Script below will take care of the divider inserting everytime you hit the 
button

```js
$(function() {
  // Disable selected checkboxes
  $('.CountryListBoxClass_prodn label input[id="UN100"], input[id="UN191"], input[id="UN372"], input[id="UN470"]').prop('disabled', true);

  // Group 'enabled' checkboxes above 'disabled'
  $('#ReformatCountries').click(function() {
    let selected = $(".CountryListBoxClass_prodn input[type='checkbox']:disabled");

    let fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    if (document.querySelector('hr') === null) fragment.appendChild(document.createElement('hr'));

    selected.each(function() {
      fragment.appendChild(this.parentElement.cloneNode(true));
      $(this).parent().remove();
    });

    document.querySelector(".CountryListBoxClass_prodn").append(fragment);
  });

}); // End function
```

```css
.CountryListBoxClass_prodn label {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  width: 213px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0px 7px 2px 0px;
}

.CountryListBoxClass_prodn input {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  bottom: 1px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.CountryListBoxClass_prodn {
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  Padding: 10px 0px 0px 5px;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  font-family: "Verdana";
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' id='ReformatCountries' value='Reformat checkboxes' />

<div class="CountryListBoxClass_prodn">

  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
        <input type="checkbox" id="UN40" value="Austria" />Austria</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
        <input type="checkbox" id="UN100" value="Bulgaria" />Bulgaria</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
        <input type="checkbox" id="UN191" value="Croatia" />Croatia</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
        <input type="checkbox" id="UN208" value="Denmark" />Denmark</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
        <input type="checkbox" id="UN233" value="Estonia" />Estonia</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
        <input type="checkbox" id="UN276" value="Germany" />Germany</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
        <input type="checkbox" id="UN348" value="Hungary" />Hungary</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
        <input type="checkbox" id="UN372" value="Ireland" />Ireland</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
        <input type="checkbox" id="UN428" value="Latvia" />Latvia</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
        <input type="checkbox" id="UN470" value="Malta"  />Malta</label>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't about selecting checkboxes.  It's about rearranging checkboxes and labels in terms of whether enabled or disabled (ie active or non active).

Comment: @Silverburch just fixed it thanks for the feedback and the selected answer inserts the `hr` divider every time you click  on the button

Comment: The `<hr>` isn't always positioned right... Check "Austria" and "Estonia" to see.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette , sorry but i didn't get what you are pointing at, the `hr` is injected once only here, are you addressing to something else when you say not positioned correctly ?

Comment: Try to check  "Austria" and "Estonia" in your snippet. Then try it in mine. ;)

Comment: i did,  it is same as before, :D i still not getting what you pointing me at.

Comment: The `<hr>` is supposed to separate the checked from the unchecked? See [printscreen](https://imgur.com/a/elpJ7)

Comment: and that is not dependent on the checking the boxes if i am right they are disabled by `js` statement, or preloaded as disabled via server side or `html` hardcoded , and they should be filtered once the button is clicked . here is the image https://imgur.com/a/MNv0o please let me know if i am wrong here

Comment: you can see the first comment under my answer as i also proposed the same solution to separate the selected :D but it wasnt the case @LouysPatriceBessette

Comment: What's the use of the `<hr>` then... If it's at a non-significative place? See the printscreen of [my snippet](https://imgur.com/a/zOaoQ)

Comment: I get the point... Your `<hr>` is at the right place, between `enabled` and `disabled`. And it is not duplicating like in the accepted answer. +1

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam many thanks for your very interesting and effective answer. It is pushing my understanding to the very limit but that's good!  Just to be clear, are you saying this is quicker than billyonecan's answer above?

Comment: if you're looping over a large data set and appending A LOT of elements use a fragment instead so you only have one reflow. If you're only appending to the dom a few times or you're only targetting modern browsers it isn't necessary. @Silverburch

Comment: you should have a read at [reflow](https://www.sitepoint.com/10-ways-minimize-reflows-improve-performance/) @Silverburch and watch this [test](https://jsperf.com/docfragment-test) on jspref

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

I totally misread the question.
The solution below is to segregate `checked` and `unchecked`... Not `enabled` and `disabled`.

I leave it there anyway since it can be usefull to one someday.

---

If you care about the alphabetical order and alignement...

You will have to order the elements based on the `input` values.
It sounds easy...

1. Get all checked and unchecked inputs in two arrays.
2. Retreive their values and order them.
3. Use the order values to append the elements in the right order.
4. Insert an horzontal line between the two.

The subtile issue about the alignment is then fixed, since ALL `label` elements have been processed.

The code below is well commented.
;)

```js
$(function() {

  // Disable selected checkboxes
  $('.CountryListBoxClass_prodn label input[id="UN100"], input[id="UN191"], input[id="UN372"], input[id="UN470"]').prop('disabled', true);

  $("#ReformatCountries").on("click",function(){
    
    // Get all checked and unchecked
    var checked_checkbox = $(".CountryListBoxClass_prodn input[type='checkbox']:checked");
    var unchecked_checkbox = $(".CountryListBoxClass_prodn input[type='checkbox']").not(":checked");

    // Based on the input value, order the checked
    var Alpha_ordered_checked = [];
    for(i=0;i<checked_checkbox.length;i++){
      Alpha_ordered_checked.push($(checked_checkbox[i]).val());
    }
    Alpha_ordered_checked = Alpha_ordered_checked.sort();

    // Based on the input value, order the unchecked
    var Alpha_ordered_unchecked = [];
    for(i=0;i<unchecked_checkbox.length;i++){
      Alpha_ordered_unchecked.push($(unchecked_checkbox[i]).val());
    }
    Alpha_ordered_unchecked = Alpha_ordered_unchecked.sort();

    // Append the checked
    for(i=0;i<Alpha_ordered_checked.length;i++){
      $(".CountryListBoxClass_prodn").append( $("input[value='"+Alpha_ordered_checked[i]+"']").parent() );
    }

    // Append an horizontal line (remove previous if any)
    $(".CountryListBoxClass_prodn").find(".hr").remove();
    $(".CountryListBoxClass_prodn").append("<hr class='hr'>");

    // Append the unchecked
    for(i=0;i<Alpha_ordered_unchecked.length;i++){
      $(".CountryListBoxClass_prodn").append( $("input[value='"+Alpha_ordered_unchecked[i]+"']").parent() );
    }
  }); // End on click

}); // End function
```

```css
.CountryListBoxClass_prodn label {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  width: 213px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0px 7px 2px 0px;
}

.CountryListBoxClass_prodn input {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  bottom: 1px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.CountryListBoxClass_prodn {
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 5px;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  font-family: "Verdana";
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='button' id='ReformatCountries' value='Reformat checkboxes' />

<div class="CountryListBoxClass_prodn">
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN40" value="Austria" />Austria</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN100" value="Bulgaria" />Bulgaria</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN191" value="Croatia" />Croatia</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN208" value="Denmark" />Denmark</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN233" value="Estonia" />Estonia</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN276" value="Germany" />Germany</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN348" value="Hungary" />Hungary</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN372" value="Ireland" />Ireland</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN428" value="Latvia" />Latvia</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN470" value="Malta" />Malta</label>
</div>
```

Comment: haha Louys this isnt what was required we need to separate the `disabled` from the `enabled` not the `checked` from `un-checked`

Comment: Haaa... Really?? Damn... Okay then.

Comment: dont worry i still love you  :D

Comment: Hahaha... I had fun in this unrequested challenge anyway.

Comment: haha i could see a lot of hard work going to be dumped here :D